# Visualforce apex:outputlink Chrome to Internet Explorer

Tags: visualforce, outputlink, chrome, internet-explorer

Any one know how to open a folder link from chrome in Windows Explorer/Intenet Explorer?

Our users use Chrome and need to open a network drive from their Salesforce. to get more flexibility, I used a Visualforce page and used outputlink. Works fine, but then want to have to see those files in Window Explore so they can upload all that.

```
<apex:outputlink value="{!'file://corp/shared/ARCHIVE/HSBOX/home/Builds/' +SUBSTITUTE(Opportunity.Name, ' ', '%20')}" id="theLink" target="_blank">
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your users install the Chrome plugin 'IE Tab' it has over 3 million users and has been around since 2009. You can find it here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Although, this only works on Windows and requires a .exe file installation, however, they do have enterprise installation options available if you contact them.